# Making a portable SFML project in codeblocks

Tags: project, codeblocks, sfml

I have made a game as my programming project using SFML in codeblocks. The thing is, my teacher wants the source code in a format that he could compile on his own pc. He doesn't have sfml nor codeblocks.

So i was wondering if there's anyway i could make my project portable so that he could simply compile it on his own pc ?

Submitting the exe file only is not permitted.

Comment: Tell your teacher that you're using SFML, and give him your source code. If he has any competence at all, he should have no problem compiling a small game.

Answer (score 1):

What do you understand under 'portable'?
Should they be portable between two Windows PCs or between two different operating systems?

Code::Blocks projects themselves are always portable even between operating systems, but for libraries it depends heavily on the used system. For two Windows version it should potentially be possible to provide the complete library (lib, headers, binaries) and simply use relative paths in the project file. But it would still require that you and your teacher use the same compiler, otherwise you could run into problems (e.g. the RC binaries don't work with a GCC version >= 4.7.x).

But as Ancurio said:

> If he [your teacher] has any competence at all, he should have no problem compiling a small game.